# how to refer to an html file using a mocha/chai test

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I have an index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #container {width: 600px; max-width: 100%; margin: 1em auto;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="enter some text" required maxlength="10" pattern="^[a-z,A-Z]{1,10}$"><br />
                <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="enter a number" required maxlength="10" pattern="\d{10}"><br />
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to run a mocha test using chai asserts on the form.

When I test an external `.js` file, I can use a `require` statement to pull in that `.js` file.

How do I reference/import an `.html` file to run tests on the form?

I can find no such information using a Google search.

Help appreciated.

**EDIT**: do I run the test in a `<script>` inside the `.html` file?

Answer (score 1):

I think I *have* found the answer.

I can use the following inside the html file.

```
<div id="mocha"></div>
<script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
<script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>

<!-- load code you want to test here -->

<!-- load your test files here -->

<script>
  mocha.run();
</script>
```

From [this page](https://www.sitepoint.com/unit-test-javascript-mocha-chai/).